# Google has compressed your app. With size compression certain configurations are now within the 0MB size limit

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I am trying to upload an apk to google play console but I am getting this warning

> "Google has compressed your app. With size compression certain
> configurations are now within the 0MB size limit."

1. what does this mean?
2. What is action to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ignored this message and published the app. it seems that Google tried to decrease the size of Distribution APK but nothing decreased, so i got

> "now within the 0MB size
> limit."